# Azure SQL Server Connection Issue

Tags: sql-server, azure, telnet, host, azure-data-studio

I'm attempting to connect to an azure sql server. My public IP was added to the IP whitelist, but when I try to connect to the server via Azure Data Studio it just keeps trying to connect with no error message (wheel keeps spinning).

I tried using telnet and it connects, but then is closed by a foreign host. Pinging the server just keeps getting request time outs and never stops tell I kill the ping in the terminal.

Not really sure the issue or how to debug this. Is it potentially an issue with how the server is setup. The person that set it up can connect with no issues.

Comment: You can double check how your public IP address appears to the internet by visiting sites like `ipchicken.com` in a web browser. If you can connect using Telnet and/or PowerShell's `Test-NetConnection -ComputerName serverNameOrIpAddress -Port 1433` but not when using Azure Data Studio then probably you have antivirus or a software firewall "helping" matters by blocking outgoing network connections.

Answer (score 0):

I created Azure SQ database and added private end point.
Image for reference:

[image]

I disabled the public access.
Image for reference:

[image]

I created VM and I tried to retrieve the IP address of server before adding private endpoint using below code:

```
nslookup dbservere.database.windows.net
```

I got below information:

[image]

After adding private end point, I got below information:

[image]
I installed telnet and tried to connect to SQL database using below code:

```
telnet <IP> 1433
```

It connected successfully.
Image for reference:

[image]

In my case it is not closed by any foreign host. we should have antivirus or set firewall while using azure data studio to block the outgoing network connections.